# How to delete a mac app that keeps opening by itself

Tags: macos

Spotify keeps opening by itself on mac. How do you delete it, when macOS does not allow you to delete open apps, and the app reopens faster than you can trash it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution: Find the app in finder and select Show Package Contents. Delete the content of this folder. Close the app, and it should be unable to open. You can now delete the app and try reinstalling it.

Comment: Worked for me, posted in case someone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity monitor to force quit the app, then use app such as AppCleaner or simply drag and drop your Spotify app from your Applications folder into trash.

Comment: I tried this solution, but Spotify kept reopening as soon as the app was closed.